# android - How to get view from context?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I want to get the view or findViewById() from Context?
Or from intent?

I'm trying to reach a specific view in my broadcast receiver and the parameter of onReceive are context and intent.

Well, I have a class and within it is my broadcast receiver.  Now, I'm trying to separate the broadcast receiver from it, but I need a way so I can still communicate with the views on my class from my separated broadcast receiver class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 80):

For example you can find any textView:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: Good answer. This is the 2015 way of doing it, the above way seems very redundant.

Comment: You can't always count on context being an instance of Activity though, can you?

Comment: That is the case if you have an Activity, so it can be casted, not a Context. This is not answering the question.

Comment: My problem is a bit different from my case but this method does what I want. Thank a lot mate!

Answer (score 67):

Starting with a context, the root view of the associated activity can be had by

```
View rootView = ((Activity)_context).Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
```

In Raw Android it'd look something like:

```
View rootView = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Then simply call the findViewById on this

```
View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);
```

Comment: Remember that you should cast `View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);` to `View v = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id);` and the class _View_ can be any derivated class of View.

Comment: When trying this I get "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity".

Comment: @drynyn that's because this example is assuming an Activity is being passed for the context, which is not a safe assumption.  You can use instanceof keyword to check if the cast is safe to perform or not. (google "instanceof java" for examples).

Answer (score 7):

In your broadcast receiver you could access a view via inflation a root layout from XML resource and then find all your views from this root layout with findViewByid():

```
View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.ROOT_LAYOUT, null);
```

Now you can access your views via 'view' and cast them to your view type:

```
myImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

Comment: What should be I placed on root parameter?

Comment: root parameter is a root View of the inflated hierarchy. In above example I have shown how to inflate a view that is already a root therefore you can keep this parameter false. If your inflated view is not a root, then you place your root view as a third parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `null` instead of `false`?

Comment: I don't think (re)inflating the entire view is a very efficient or reliable approach, seeing that it is already inflated with a call to `setContentView()`. However, if you omit the call to 'setContentView()` and manually attached it after a manual inflation then you may be ok (I forgot exactly how to do this, but manual view attachment can be done in any `Activity` or `Fragment`).

Answer (score 1):

first use this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Read_file.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Read file is current activity in which you want your context.

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_name_id));
```

then you can use this to find any element in layout.

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use a singleton?

```
import android.content.Context;


public class ClassicSingleton {
    private Context c=null;
    private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
    protected ClassicSingleton()
    {
       // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
    }
    public void setContext(Context ctx)
    {
    c=ctx;
    }
    public Context getContext()
    {
       return c;
    }
    public static ClassicSingleton getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new ClassicSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then in the activity class:

```
 private ClassicSingleton cs = ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
```

And in the non activity class:

```
ClassicSingleton cs= ClassicSingleton.getInstance();
        Context c=cs.getContext();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) ((Activity)c).findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: Nice try, but unfortunately this will introduce a memory leak since `ClassicSingleton` will hold a reference to Activity.