# android - listview filter count

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, filtering, android-adapter

So after I set the filter on my listview:

```
//Log adapter count before filter
listView.getFilter().filter(searchStr)
//Log adapter count after filter
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the count of the result of that filtering.  Like if before there are 10 items, then I apply the filter, so now only 5 items will appear, I want to get that count "5".  I've tried checking the adapter count before and after the filter with no luck.  They're displaying same count (I'm using a BaseExpandableListAdapter) if I apply filter, and if I apply filter again the number changes from before (but the before and after of filter is still the same).

Below is a sample result of what I'm getting on my logs:

```
Before filter the count is 10. After filter the count is 10.
Before filter the count is 8.  After filter the count is 8.
```

I thought maybe my adapter doesn't get the reflected count right away but on the second filter, it changes the value, so I thought notifyDataSetChanged after the filter would make a difference, but it did not.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

```
myAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchText, new Filter.FilterListener() {
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
         Log.d("log", "result count:" + count);
    }
});
```

Comment: this actually solved me the original problem, plus another one: my list was appearing with all elements for a fraction of a second, due to the fact the filter runs in Asynctask transparently, and setAdapter was being called before publishResults actually happened

Comment: Missing ); in your code,,,its open near filter( but no close bracket.so add ); at end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114966/android-how-to-get-view-from-context

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `listview.getCount()` after applying the filter.

Comment: I'm using ExpandableListView.  And using that returns the group count not the child count on each group.