# How to check if an adapter filter doesn't correspond to any entries in a listview

Tags: java, android

Does "getFilter().filter();" on a simple adapter have a way to check if a listview has that particular entry ?

I have this code:

```
String tempString = searchField.getText().toString();

    if (tempString != "") {
         MainActivityFragment.adapter.getFilter().filter(tempString);
         MainActivityFragment.actionbar.setSubtitle("Search Results");
    }

    else {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "The Search Field can't be empty !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

I'd like to know if "filter(tempString);" is true (it exists in a particular listview). If not maybe prompt the user with a message.

Comment: Not sure that it's an exact duplicate so I'll just link this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628453/android-listview-filter-count. You can count the results after applying a filter. Unless your question was about knowing before hand; if that's the case then please edit it to specify so.

Comment: This solved my problem, please post is as an answer to be able to accept it.

Comment: Done. But if the linked question is what solved the issue maybe we should mark this one as a duplicate of that for the future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question here that may or may not be a duplicate so I'll just link this here: [android - listview filter count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628453/android-listview-filter-count).

You can count the results after applying a filter. Unless your question was about knowing before hand; if that's the case then please edit your question to specify so and we can try a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Filter method is started asynchronous as what the documentation said:

```
Starts an asynchronous filtering operation. Calling this method cancels all previous non-executed filtering requests and posts a new filtering request that will be executed later.
```

**solution:**

You could create an interface and pass it to your adapter and in the `publishResults()` you could count the number of filtered data in the `FilterResults` class by `results.count()`..

if the count is 0 then call ur interface and you could put your message inside that interface..