# Xamarin - Get adapter's filter count

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using a listView which is filled with an adapter, which has a filter.
Filter works good, and updates listView, with notifyDataSetChanged.
But now I want to show the number of listview items.

I tryed

```
searchView.QueryTextChange += (sender, e) => {
                _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter (e.NewText);
                Title = _adapter.Count; // also tryed listView.Count
            };
```

but it shows the number of items of the last search, not the current. Is there like a Filter listener so I can have updated results?

[android - listview filter count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628453/android-listview-filter-count)

I saw this, but how can I implement it in Xamarin?

Comment: Can you post your adapter code? You'll need to add a filter listener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.FilterListener.html to listen for the completion of the filter, this will give you a count.

Comment: That was it... just didn't know how to do it... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should implement `IFilterListener`. Then you add your class instance to the InvokeFilter method resulting in the Interface methods being called when your filter has completed.

```
class MyClass : Android.Widget.Filter.IFilterListener
{
    ...

        searchView.QueryTextChange += (sender, e) => 
        {
            _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText, this);
        };

    ...

    public void OnFilterComplete(int count)
    {
        Title = count.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. App crashes when I try to filter.